# Move files to BLOB using Automate

Tags: azure-blob-storage, power-automate

I want to move files my email to attachment to Azure BLOB using Power Automate. I am aware of the BLOB storage connection but I can't use it as I don't have the access key.

After surfing Google, I managed to find the below link. I need help on how to get the x-ms header and how to choose the folder inside the BLOB to upload the file into.

I lack all kind on experience in HTTP and Azure BLOB. :(

Please help.

Link: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/how-to-upload-to-blob-container-via-sas-url/m-p/125756#M3360

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end, Here is how we could able to save files in our blob from the HTTP connector.

[image]

We have used “x-ms-blob-type” as a header with a value of “BlockBlob”. Make sure you add the path to your storage account in URI in the below format.

```
https://<STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER NAME>/<FILE NAME><SAS>
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

[image]